# I'm trying to convert a Korean otf font to json so that I can use it as Text3D in R3F, but it's not showing up properly

Tags: text, fonts, cjk, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

Facetype.js isn't allowing me to convert Korean fonts when 'reverse font direction' is selected.
Also, if I generate the json font without that selected characters overlap, and the order is backwards.

I usually use Facetype.js to convert my fonts to json for conversion to 3D, and that worked for this Korean Google Font, but only if I don't select 'reverse font direction', which is necessary for the characters to display correctly.
I tried using the json font that was generated without that selected--the letters are hollowed out and when I type anything the characters overlap. If I put about 2 spaces inbetween then there is separation but 'ㅁ ㄴ' for example appears as 'ㄴ ㅁ', so the order is flipped.
If anyone has an idea of how I can get Korean text displaying correctly please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found this fork of Facetype.js and it's compatible with CJK languages!!
Solved all the issues I was having:  troy351.github.io/facetype.js